# Giveaway command time discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hey guys I need help to make a giveaway command that shows time in day/hours/mins/seconds
Right now i was only able to make the time in seconds in the giveaway message
I found some way to make the time in day/hours/mins/seconds in the command but not for the message sended by the bot.

**I hope it made sense if it didn't I am sorry**

Here is my code:

```
@bot.command(aliases=["gcreate"])
async def gstart(ctx, gtime,*, prize):
    if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
        time=convert(gtime)
        gembed=discord.Embed(title=f"<a:giveaway:828219055017951292> {prize}", description=f"⏳Time Left : {time} seconds\nHosted by : {ctx.author.mention}\nReact with <a:Tada:812191920238886922> to participate", color=0xFF5733)
        msg=await ctx.send(f"<a:Gift:828220390551453777> **GIVEAWAY** <a:Gift:828220390551453777>", embed=gembed)
        await msg.add_reaction("<a:Tada:812191920238886922>")
        while time:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            time-=1
            gembed.description=f"⏳Time Left : {time} seconds\nHosted by : {ctx.author.mention}\nReact with <a:Tada:812191920238886922> to participate"
            await msg.edit(embed=gembed)
        new_msg=await ctx.channel.fetch_message(msg.id)
        users=await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        users.pop(users.index(bot.user))
        winner = random.choice(users)
        gembed.description=f"Winner : {winner.mention}\nHosted by : {ctx.author.mention}"
        await msg.edit(content=f"<a:Gift:828220390551453777> **GIVEAWAY ENDED** <a:Gift:828220390551453777>", embed=gembed)
        await ctx.send(f"Congratulations! {winner.mention} you won the giveaway of `{prize}`\nDm {ctx.author.mention} for your Rewards!")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Sorry {ctx.author.mention} but you do not have enough perms to use this command\n**__PERMS NEEDED__** <a:arrow_r:825382670514389072> Manage Messages")
@gstart.error
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Try again in this format:\n""`[!gstart | !gcreate] {time[s|m|h|d]} {prize}`")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whats the issue ? Please be clear and clarify your problem.

Comment: I want to make the timer which us shown in the giveaway embed in days/hours/minutes/seconds, I could only make it so it shows the timer in seconds.

Comment: i can't add images or i would have added images to show what i meant